why JavaScript code export to excel working with old office extension xls but not working with xlsx?
I working on export html table to excel using JAVASCRIPT . I face issue it not export to excel office New version with extension xlsx .
but it working fine and export to old version office excel with extension xls .
when export from html table to excel new version with xlsx extension it give me error
cannot open file `.xlsx` because file extension is not valid or file corrupted .

so How to solve this issue to working with xlsx extension and open new version excel .
`function getselected_civilid() {
    debugger
    var selectedCivilIds = [];
    $("input[name='statusCheckbox']:checked").each(function () {
        selectedCivilIds.push($(this).val());
    });

    if (selectedCivilIds.length > 0) {
        // Create an HTML table with headers
        var table = "<table><tr><th>م</th><th>رقم السجل التجاري</th><th>رقم الترخيص</th><th>رقم الجهه المدني</th><th>الكيان القانوني</th><th>المحافظة</th><th>القطاع</th><th>كود النشاط الدولى</th><th>اسم المنشأة</th><th>العنوان</th><th>الرقم الالي للعنوان</th><th>المدينة</th><th>رقم التليفون</th><th>البريد الالكترونى</th></tr>";

     
        $("input[name='statusCheckbox']:checked").each(function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Get the parent row of the checkbox
            var cells = row.find("td"); // Get all the cells in the row

            table += "<tr>";
            cells.each(function () {
                table += "<td>" + $(this).text() + "</td>"; // Add each cell value to the table
            });
            table += "</tr>";
        });

        table += "</table>";

     
        var blob = new Blob([table], {
            type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"
        });
 
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "LastData.xls"; // Set the filename for the downloaded file
        link.click();
    }
}`

when debug var table it give me html table script as fiddle below so How to export to excel xlsx New version
https://jsfiddle.net/36s1qhov

How to replace part below with sheet jz to export to excel xlsx
var blob = new Blob([table], {
            type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"
        });
 
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "LastData.xls"; // Set the filename for the downloaded file
        link.click();


Does this answer your question? How to export an HTML table as a .xlsx file

so how to install this on my project  TableExport by clarketm i work on javascript on visual studio 2019

You should not ask Stackoverflow how to use a Javascript library, that is something you should research on your own. There is also plenty of documentation on how to use it. https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport

can you please help me i need cdn first for table export then how to use it inside javascript function i added

@AndyRay same could be said for anything, including "javascript" itself.  There are plenty of libraries authors that actually suggest asking on SO about their library.

"xlsx" is not just a file extension, its actually a format of a zip package that contains XML and other files.
you can't just name the file "something.xlsx", you need to package it.
use existing library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx for this.

how to install it on sheetjs or use it on JavaScript
link you send support type script not javascript
